# Need Help in implementation of vigenere cipher

Tags: java

I need help implementing a Vigenere Cipher. My input string "Cat&Dog" with the key "abc" should return "Cbv&Eqg" but I'm getting "cat&eqg" with the code shown below.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "Cat&dog";
        String b = "abc";
        String c = encrypt(a , b);
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    public static String encrypt (String text, String key){
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
            char cur = text.charAt(i);
            if (cur > 'a' && cur < 'z'){
                result += (char)((cur + key.charAt(j) - 2 * 'a') % 26 +'a');
                j = ++j % key.length();
            }
            else if (cur <= 'A' && cur >= 'Z'){
                result += (char)((cur - key.charAt(j) -2 * 'a') % 26 +'A');
                j = ++j % key.length();
            }
            else {
                result += text.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hear is an [example](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Java)

Comment: I edited my post. Try this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case `else if(cur <= 'A' && cur >= 'Z')` will never be true. 
There is no x with `x <= 65 && x >= 90`.

And you neet to subtract an 'A' and add the key in case of capital letter.

So here the solution:

```
public static String encrypt (String text, String key){
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
        char cur = text.charAt(i);
        if (cur >= 'a' && cur <= 'z'){
            result += (char) ((cur + key.charAt(j) - 2 * 'a') % 26 + 'a');
        }
        else if (cur >= 'A' && cur <= 'Z'){
            result += (char) ((cur - 'A' + key.charAt(j) - 'a') % 26 + 'A');
        }
        else {
            result += text.charAt(i);
        }
        j = ++j % key.length();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Output for "Cat&Dog" wit key = "abc":

> Cbv&Eqg

Comment: That is true, but is no answer to the question or a solution to the problem.

Comment: With the code you provide now your answer is valid and correct.

Comment: with the code you provide 90% is correct but the e should be uppercase in "eqg".

Comment: The result was lower case, as my input was lower case. But the code works also with upper case. See my edit

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the solution